# Mask values in a SQL Query string for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-masking, pii

I am a SQL Server DBA. I would like to write a procedure which I can provide to rest of my team where they can view the text for currently running queries on the server (Similar to how we view in sp_who2) but with all the values masked.
Examples:

| Query text | Query text after Masking |
| --- | --- |
| Select * from sometable where rating = '**4**' | Select * from sometable where rating = '****' |
| Select name, id from sometable where id = '**3233**' | Select name, id from sometable where id = '****' |
| UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = '**Alfred Schmidt**' WHERE CustomerID = **1**; | UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = '****' WHERE CustomerID = ****; |
| INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName) VALUES ('**Cardinal**', '**Tom B. Erichsen**'); | INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName) VALUES ('*****', '****'); |

Comment: Hard to do this using regular SQL Server code.  If your stored proc has access to a regex replacement function, then replace `'.*?'` with `'****'`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah. that is a good recommendation. Any suggestion to deal with integer as well like in the third example?

Comment: Is regex even a possibility for you?

Comment: Actually doesn't seem like I have it, but I am thinking it might be not too hard to write a regex replace method in sql...

Comment: Doing anything useful like performance tuning is going to be hit and miss without parameter values.  What's the actual end goal? Do you have an XY problem?

Comment: Are running queries parameterized and using stored procedures? If so it's easy to just provide the SQL of the procedure or batch without the parameters

Comment: For the simple queries in the question you could execute sys.sp_get_query_template to get the template (if you don’t mind the letter case) and the corresponding variables of forced parameterization of a query, split the list of variables and replace them in the template with `**,N*, *.*, 0x** according to each variable type. The downside is that the procedure raises an error if it cannot parameterise a query. For complex queries, you could call a CLR object which implements a Parser, parse a query and replace the literals/constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some XML-trickery to handle the strings.
First replace all single quotes with an empty tag `<X/>` to get a XML that looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName) 
  VALUES (<X />Cardinal<X />, <X />Tom B. Erichsen<X />);
```

Then you shred the xml to get the text nodes and the node numbers where mod 2 is 0 is the ones you want to mask.

After that you can rebuild your query string using the mask values.

I have not found a way to deal with numbers other then removing all numbers from the query using [Translate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or nested replace and that will of course also remove numbers from table names and column names as well.

You could try something like this.

```
declare @S nvarchar(max);
declare @X xml;

set @S = N'UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = ''Alfred Schmidt'' WHERE CustomerID = 1;';

set @X = replace(@S, '''', '<X/>');

with C as
(
  select T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as V, 
         row_number() over(order by T.X) as RN
  from @X.nodes('text()') as T(X)
)
select @S = (
            select case when C.RN % 2 = 0 then '''*****''' else C.V end
            from C
            order by C.RN
            for xml path(''), type
            ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

set @S = translate(@S, '0123456789', '**********')

print @S;
```

Result:

```
UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = '*****' WHERE CustomerID = *;
```

Note: Just realized that this solution does not handle the cases where the string values contains single quotes but I think this is something that possibly can inspire more robust solution so I will leave it here.

Comment: I really like this solution Mikael, the only case which I am not able to figure out the case where there is a number in the table name. something like where table name is mytable878 it gets changed to mytable*** right now..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your issue.
You can use this query:

```
select 
    r.session_id,
    r.status,
    r.command,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time,
    t.text
from sys.dm_exec_requests as r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) as t
```

e.g.
I run it on my SQL server right now:

```
(@P1 nvarchar(5),@P2 bigint,@P3 int,@P4 numeric(28, 12),@P5 nvarchar(5),@P6 datetime,@P7 datetime)
SELECT SUM(A.SETTLEAMOUNTCUR) FROM CUSTSETTLEMENT A,CUSTTRANS B WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (((A.TRANSRECID=@P2) AND (A.CANBEREVERSED=@P3)) AND (A.SETTLEAMOUNTCUR<>@P4))) AND ((B.DATAAREAID=@P5) AND (((B.RECID=A.OFFSETRECID) AND (B.TRANSDATE>=@P6)) AND (B.TRANSDATE<=@P7)))
```

All variables are hidden.

Comment: Are you sure it is not your client application that transforms the queries to that form? When I append `where r.session_id = 99` to your query and run it, I get back the entire query as is, i.e. it has `99` coded in it without any `@P1` introduced.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó This is because the query is parameterized, as all queries should be. The above output is what XEvents and SQL Profiler return in such cases.

Comment: @Charlieface But then does this mean that this can not be a solution for the OP's queries, which are not parameterized, apparently? EDIT: I've  just seen you asked this in comment.

Answer (score 0):

[sys.sp_get_query_template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-get-query-template-transact-sql)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=080b2c4d56a58889309e808f8e78963f)

```sql
declare @t nvarchar(max), @p nvarchar(max);
declare @q nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = N''Alfred Schmidt'' WHERE CustomerID = 1 AND Rate = 0.75 AND Rver = 0x0102 AND DateCreated = dateadd(day, -10, ''202z0818'')';

exec sys.sp_get_query_template @querytext = @q, @templatetext = @t OUTPUT, @parameters = @p OUTPUT;

select p,
  case when tp like '%int' then cast('****' as nvarchar(40))
  when tp like 'decimal(%' or tp like 'numeric(%' then '**.**'
  when tp like '%binary(%' then '0x****'
  when tp like 'n%char%' then 'N''****'''
  else '''****'''
  end as rv
into #t
from
(
select *, '@'+left(s.value, charindex(' ', s.value+' ')-1) as p, stuff(s.value, 1, charindex(' ', s.value), '') as tp
from string_split(replace(@p, ',@', '@'), '@') as s
where s.value <> ''
) as ss;

update #t
set @t = replace(@t, p, rv);

select @q union all select @t;
```